# std::priority_queue different comparisons

Tags: c++, constructor, priority-queue

I want to construct three different `priority_queue`'s that hold a class `Thing` and then sort each one differently by values that are held by the `Thing`. I know that I can define an operator method either internally, or a friend to the object, but is there a way to have it use different test method(s)? How do I tell it to use that method instead of the operator method? And how would the parameter list differ from creating an operator overload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like most STL containers, the `priority_queue` accepts a [Compare class in its template arguments](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/priority_queue/).

```
struct MyCompare1 {
  bool operator()(const Thing& t1, const Thing& t2) {
    // your logic here
  }
};

std::priority_queue<Thing, std::vector<Thing>, MyCompare1> my_queue;
```

Comment: how do i preface this. can you point to some documentation that explains this (writing, using)

Comment: does the method have to be its own class/struct, or can it be a member function as well similar to making a member operator<(const Thing& _t2).

Comment: visual studio throws that operator must be non-static, and made me define an operator

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a custom comparator type that will be used instead of the default. This is a template parameter of the `priority_queue`.

Comment: how do i preface this. can you point to some documentation that explains this (writing, using)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your comparison function as the third parameter when defining the [priority_queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue). Note that the second parameter is the underlying container type, typically `std::vector`.

```
std::priority_queue<Thing> pq1;
std::priority_queue<Thing, std::vector<Thing>, std::greater<Thing> > pq2;
std::priority_queue<Thing, std::vector<Thing>, [your comparator here] > pq3;
```